# Seemingly random numbers with a hidden pattern

Tags: number-sequence

I bring a set of numbers with a hidden pattern. Those who can uncover the pattern deserve a Noble prize for their efforts. Good luck.

> 4, 20, 39, 83, 131, 222, 294.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are the

> Atomic weights of the noble gases

As clued by

> "Noble Prize"

Comment: I bet you're right but in that case 83 should surely be 84.

Comment: Argon's mass=40 not 39(OK, 39.9)

Comment: For the record, I got my numbers from a table and then rounded everything down.